# Laravel keep information about users on multiple sessions

Tags: session, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm implementing my database. xD
Should I make changes, but I would like any further information about it, by those who are more experienced than me.

1) Should I make sure to keep a tracking for security reasons.
I would like to create a table "access", which contains the following fields.
id, id_user, browser, os, dates, ip.

What should I change, to ensure that each time the user login, is added a new record in this table.

If you have more tips on how to improve this point, I'd be grateful.

2) I would like to do so you can make the user choose whether the session of his choice or whether permanent or not.
I could only find a way to do it, that the session lasting for a certain period of time.
But I would like to implement a graft.

3) Should I implement multiple sessions, I'll explain.
The possibility that every user experience their sessions, such as facebook ago.
You can see how many active sessions exist and on what date.
I thought at a table like this:
id, id_user, queues, browser, os, dates, ip.

What do you think, you can do what?
If yes, what should I change in the structure of laravel to do this?

Thank you in advance who will help me.
I apologize for my English and the long text.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should use also timestamp that logging table. You can use the built in updated_at and created_at timestamps. In your login function simply create a new instance of the model, populate the attributes and save() it.

2) There is a built in remember me behavior that you can use. More details can be found in the Laravel docs http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

3) Can you explain more of why you would want to implement multiple sessions? Why would this be useful for your application?

I hope my answer helps.

Comment: Meanwhile, I thank you for having responded.
The second point I managed to implement it.
Now to the other.

1) I'd prefer to use an external table, so you may want to check if their accesses. But I do not know how to do that during the authentication phase, and if the data is correct, add a new record in this table.

Comment: 3) A user could access from different devices, "Pc, table, mobile phone, etc .."
and could have more sessions aperte.Se the user wants to check all open sessions with his account, and could do so if he wanted to, could also decide to delete them, so the only open session that would remain his and if you were to hook up with a device that had previously carried out a session, but now the session of the db no longer exists, the user should not be connected with the account. I do not know if I was clear. :)

Comment: 1) You can implement this in a different table by simply creating another database model such as "AccessLogs". You can then at the end of your login script create a new instance of AccessLogs, map the appropriate attributes, and `save()` the new model.

3) This makes a lot of sense. Are you looking for help implementing this?

Comment: Yes, I would be very grateful. ;)